# Is there any standard way to apply charges to users when minting and listing their NFT using my app?

Tags: transactions, ether, ethereum-wallet-dapp, nft, ios

In my iOS app, I want the users simply mint their NFT and list on marketplace using their wallet and in return they will give me a tiny portion of fees when processing.

**Is there any standards to do that ? Should I make it defined on the contract about how he pay the fee ? Or any other ideas ?**

Also when the users need to fund their wallet, can I provide him the fund using in-app purchase ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add that in the smart contract, otherwise, users would be able to circumvent it.

```
uint creatorFee = 0.0099 ether // creatorFee is 0.01, now we can save some gas in require statement

function mint() public payable {
    require(msg.value > creatorFee); // by only using > instead of >=
    
    // code ...
}
```

If you want users to be able to fund their wallets, Fiat -> Crypto, you can use a third party crypto payment API and integrate it into your app. You wont be allowed to do this otherwise, because of financial legislations.

Comment: Thanks a bunch @normal_human ! About funding users wallet , "Fiat -> Crypto" how does it work ? I don't know about fiat yet. Have any suitable resource you can share  please ?

Comment: Here's an article to give you some base knowledge on fiat onramp API's [link](https://hackernoon.com/what-is-the-best-fiat-on-ramp-for-your-crypto-appwebsite-ss1x33oc). One option is [link](https://onramper.com). Most of them have a widget that you can embed in your website so users do not have to leave your site/app to buy crypto!